# Select a value from specific table with `where` clause on another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I do something like this in a Single MySQL Query?

```
select `value_a` 
from `table_1` 
where `value_b` = (select `value_b` from `table_2` where `value_c` = `x`);
```

I use CodeIgniter so I can use Active Records.

Comment: Yes, there is.. What you have is essentially correct. Have you even TRIED to do it?

Comment: Thanks, yes I did but I received an 'Unknown Column' error. I thought I might be missing something

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a column. Most likely `value_a`, `value_b` or `value_c`

Comment: Is than `x` a column or a value? If it's a value, remove the backquotes: `where \`value_c\` = x`

Comment: Thank you `Leeish` and `ypercube`. What ypercube mentioned was my ridicules mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use a `JOIN` for this:

```
select t1.value_a
from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2
  on t1.value_b = t2.value_b
where t2.value_c = 'x'
```

You can also use your existing query, but the `x` is surrounded by backticks and not single quotes:

```
select `value_a` 
from `table_1` 
where `value_b` = (select `value_b` from `table_2` where `value_c` = 'x);
```

Comment: someone tested performance differences on this?