# WHERE statement with one to many option

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query

```
UPDATE TBL$TEMPLATE_PARAM
   SET NAME='new_name'
   WHERE NAME='old_name' AND FIXED_VALUE='some_value';
```

I want improve it with one more WHERE expression: `AND BEAN_NAME='bean'` but `BEAN_NAME` is a row from other table `TBL$TEMPLATE`.

Its one to many (one template - many template params). `TBL$TEMPLATE_PARAM` store `TEMPLATE_ID` and its a foreign key to ID of TEMPLATE.

What is a best way to write `WHERE NAME='old_name' AND FIXED_VALUE='some_value' AND TBL$TEMPLATE.BEAN_NAME='bean'`?

Comment: 1 option use exists keyword and a join ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389891/select-a-value-from-specific-table-with-where-clause-on-another-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
UPDATE TBL$TEMPLATE_PARAM
SET    NAME='new_name'
WHERE  NAME='old_name' AND 
       FIXED_VALUE='some_value' AND
       TBL$TEMPLATE_PARAM.TEMPLATE_ID IN (SELECT ID
                                          FROM   TBL$TEMPLATE
                                          WHERE  BEAN_NAME='bean')
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Mureinik's solution, but for completeness sake, I figured I would provide a solution which uses a `merge` statement.

Since we know that there is a many to one relationship between the table being updated,`TBL$TEMPLATE_PARAM`, and the table being used to filter out records, `TBL$TEMPLATE`, the `merge` statement is well suited.

Specifically, as the [Oracle documentation states (11g)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm), "You cannot update the same row of the target table multiple times in the same MERGE statement"

Knowing the type of relationship between these tables is essential when using a `merge` statement.

Here is my alternate solution:

```
MERGE INTO tbl$template_param ttp USING tbl$template tt ON (ttp.template_id = tt.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET ttp.NAME        ='new_name'
  WHERE 1             = 1
  AND tt.bean_name    = 'bean'
  AND ttp.NAME        = 'old_name'
  AND ttp.fixed_value = 'some_value';
```